# UPDATE cql is not working, table is not updating

Tags: cassandra, sql-update, cql

My CQL:

```
UPDATE BBS_ID.users SET access_token='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjb2RlIjoiNzIxMjk2IiwibmJmIjoxNjY4MTA0NTM5LCJleHAiOjE2NjgxMDgxMzgsImlhdCI6MTY2ODEwNDUzOX0.-1CSN-I2ppFmO9Q6O2y1b2rl_0z0gdvpPeGxEnadinI' WHERE email = 'luuqe'
```

users table
The `access_token` is `varchar`
[image]

Comment: What consistency was used for the Write and the Read operations? How many replicas are set for the table?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Also, what is the primary key definition?